# Nodejs - How to use morgan with debug

Tags: node.js, express, logging, morgan, npm-debug

[Morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) outputs requests directly to the console.

How can I redirect them to npm [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) so that it follows the same format as the other stuff which is being logged?

My `debug.js` config looks like the following:

```
import debug from 'debug';

const LOG_PREFIX = 'api';

const info = debug(`${LOG_PREFIX}:info`);
const dev = debug(`${LOG_PREFIX}:dev`);
const error = debug(`${LOG_PREFIX}:error`);

export {
  info,
  dev,
  error,
};
```

And I currently log other stuff like:

```
import { info } from './debug';

info('App is up and running!');
```

My current morgan call is:

```
app.use(morgan('combined'));
```

Comment: Better to use express-winston. It can log a lot of things to different transports like file, console, newtork, db. Lot of things that morgan cannot do. Highly configurable. I replaced morgon because I couldn't make it log into MongoDB easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Morgan accepts an optional parameter which is the [stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#stream).

By default it points to `process.stdout`, the console.

Since what it does it to call `stream.write`, you can easily build a quick stream which redirects to your `debug`.

```
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: { write: msg => info(msg) } }));
```

Generically (but still **ES6**), that would be:

```
import debug from 'debug';
const info = debug('info');
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: { write: msg => info(msg) } }));
```

**ES5**:

```
var info = require('debug')('info');
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: { write: function(msg) { info(msg); } }}));
```

Comment: What if I wanted it to go to MongoDB?

Comment: @NidhinDavid whilst I'm pretty sure there are libraries which already do that for you in a very efficient way, a quick solution would be to simply change `info(msg)` to something like `db.collection('logs').insertOne({ msg, date })`

Comment: Do you think MongoDb supports write streams

Answer (score 5):

when using morgan ˋstreamˋ combined with ˋdebugˋ, it´s best to do:

```
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: { write: msg => info(msg.trimEnd()) } }));
```

The reason: morgan add a new line at the end of the msg when calling the `stream.write(...)` function.