# Is it possible to use winston logging and debug module together?

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I use [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logging because I use its features like different logging levels, multiple transports, etc.

But I also like [debug's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) namespace feature. Besides, express already uses it. So is it possible to use them together, e.g. to let winston logging have namespace?

Comment: Feels hacky but you can wrap `debug.log` with winston. [ref](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/239#issuecomment-162959969)

Answer (score 11):

After using several different loggers I gain more insight about nodejs loggers, now I believe they are not supposed to be used together b/c they are designed for different purposes. On the other hand, morgan and winston can be used together, e.g. [Node.js - logging / Use morgan and winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906551/node-js-logging-use-morgan-and-winston), morgan and debug can be used together too, [Nodejs - How to use morgan with debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009672/nodejs-how-to-use-morgan-with-debug)

But first of all, to quote from [Logging in Node.js done right](http://www.jyotman.xyz/post/logging-in-node.js-done-right)

> Setting up proper logging in Node.js applications can be bit
> overwhelming at first due to the plethora of modules available through
> NPM.

That was indeed my situation when I had morgan, winston, debug together. But then I realized they are for different purposes with overlaps. So I use debugjs when I really debug an issue instead of using console.log(some said debugjs is not a logger).  After I am done with it I turn that debug off.

Morgan is to log express HTTP request specifically. Better to use it in dev/prod env for different purposes.

Using different log levels for Winston in dev/prod env is probably a common practice. I can also use [express-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston) to log HTTP request instead of using morgan.

Winston uses a different log level to turn off some log, unlike debugjs to use namespace to turn log off so I don't think they can work together.

--- update 2021 ---

Since I first answered my own question in 2018, I was asked several times about the log level related question. I found an [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/780) opened against debugjs confirmed what I said about debug, to quote the answer from its current maintainer

> Debug isn't a general purpose logging library, it's meant to
> conditionally turn on debug logs. There is no concept of log levels.
> Instead, break up your namespaces into different components and enable
> the ones you care about

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to start passing debug(...) calls into winston. You can override  the [debug.log](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/src/node.js#L189) function to achieve that.

```
const logger  = require('./v1/lib/logger'); //my winston logger
const util    = require('util');
const debug     = require('debug');

//for testing and dev use the regular debug (optional) 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  debug.log = (...args) => logger.info(util.format(...args))
}

module.exports =  debug;
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `debug` and `winston`, you may also want to override `formatArgs` function, since  `debug.log` is receiving already colored arguments (depending on enviroment) and it may have unexpected results in some cases (e.g. setting env vs module loading order).

```
import debug from "debug";
import util from "util";
import winston from "winston";

// create winston logger
const logger = new winston.Logger({ /*...*/ });

// keep original arguments
debug.formatArgs = (args) => { /* do nothing */ };
// override logging (keep function to use `this`)
debug.log = function(...args) {
  // log to winston
  logger.log("info", {
    // `this` is bound to debug instance
    namespace: this.namespace,
    // format as in `console.log`
    message: util.format(...args),
    // add message time
    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    // optionally log also diff time
    diff: '+' + debug.humanize(this.diff),
  });
};
// enable all debug
debug.enable('*');
```